# How to store the values of a checkbox in an array in the order in which it is check

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying for a user to choose items base on priorities, and I have four items.

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="1">Mano      
 <input type="checkbox" value="2">Nalo      
 <input type="checkbox" value="3">keke      
 <input type="checkbox" value="4">aji
```

user `A` can choose
       `[3,1,2,4]`
   user `B` can choose
       `[1,2,3,4]`
    user `C` can choose
       `[3,2,1,4]`

```
function addPrior()
{
   // if check
    addToArray();
   // when uncheck
   removeToArray();
}
```

Comment: sounds like you've got the idea. You just need to handle the checked event of each checkbox. Possible problem though - how does the prioritisation work if the user un-checks an option and then checks it again? Does it go to the bottom of the list? You might be better off with some UI that lets them drag and drop the items into the right order. I can see users finding this a bit confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, Here you will get each checkbox details in you function by `event` property. So you can use them further.

```
<script>
 function addPrior( e)
 {
   // if check
   if(e.target.checked){
      addToArray(e.target);
   }else{
      removeToArray(e.target);
   }
 }
 var arr = [];
 function addToArray(obj){
   arr.push(obj.value)
 }
 function removeToArray(obj){
 var index = arr.indexOf(obj.value);
 if (index > -1) {
    arr.splice(index, 1);
  }
 }

</script>
```

HTML

```
 <input type="checkbox"  value="1" onchange="addPrior(event)">Mano         
 <input type="checkbox" value="2" onchange="addPrior(event)">Nalo       
 <input type="checkbox" value="3" onchange="addPrior( event)">keke       
 <input type="checkbox"  value="4" onchange="addPrior( event)">aji
```

Comment: just one tricks!! The checkbox set is in a loop, how can I set the hidden field to each array of values as it is looping

Comment: you want to create a hidded field in html with values from array stored checkbox values?

Comment: yes, but the checkbox group is in a loop. So as it is looping each checkbox group will be set to the hidden field

Comment: can you create a plunker, and put your basic code(HTML and JS) there i'll do the things for you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. The code below give you order list in hidden field `( id = orderArr )`.

```
<div>
        <input onchange="makeArr(this)" type="checkbox"  value="Mano">         
        <input onchange="makeArr(this)" type="checkbox" value="Nalo">       
        <input onchange="makeArr(this)" type="checkbox" value="keke">       
        <input onchange="makeArr(this)" type="checkbox"  value="aji">

        <input type="hidden" id="orderArr" value="">
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">     
            function makeArr(el){
                // console.log(el)
                var orderArr = $('#orderArr').val();
                if(orderArr != ''){
                    orderArr = JSON.parse($('#orderArr').val());
                }else{
                    orderArr = [];
                }
                if($(el).is(':checked')){
                    orderArr.push({order: $(el).val()});
                }else{
                    orderArr.forEach(function (el, i, obj){
                        if(elem.order ==  $(el).val()){                         
                        orderArr.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                    });
                }
                $("#orderArr").val(JSON.stringify(orderArr));
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: The checkbox set is in a loop,  how can I set the hidden field to the orderArray   as it is looping

Comment: sorry @LaminLJanneh m not able get you which loop you are talking about. But if you are talking about my code then I am getting hidden field value in `var orderArr` and then setting back to hidden field here `$("#orderArr").val` in last line

Comment: I think according to the asked question, **hidden field** is better than **global variable**

Answer (score -1):

```
<input name='select_list[]' type="checkbox"  value="1">Mano         
<input name='select_list[]' type="checkbox" value="2">Nalo       
<input name='select_list[]' type="checkbox" value="3">keke       
<input name='select_list[]' type="checkbox"  value="4">aji


var checked = []
$("input[name='select_list[]']:checked").each(function () {
    checked.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
});
```

Comment: I don't think this works, also `wizard_list[]` matches nothing.

Comment: I want it to be stored in the order in which they are checked

Comment: please change wizard_list[] to select_list[]

Comment: this will not give the required order list.